# perl background process

Tags: perl, background, fork, sleep, wait

I am trying to run a background process in perl. I create a child process, which is used to call another perl script. I want to run few lines of code parallely with this child process. And after the child process is done.I want to print a line of code.

#### Main script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$|=1;

print "before the child process\n";

my $pid = fork();

if (defined $pid)
{
    system("perl testing.pl");
}

print "before wait command\n";

wait();

print "after 20 secs of waiting\n";
```

#### testing.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "inside testing\n";

sleep(20);
```

#### Expected output

```
before the child process
before wait command
(should wait for 20 secs and then print)
after 20 secs of waiting
```

Comment: So what are you seeing instead?  It's worth noting that everything after the `system` call will get executed by *both* the parent and the child process.

Comment: u r right.. it is printing it twice. how do i control that?

Comment: *[dreamer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/768206/dreamer)*: It is because `0` **is** a *`defined`* value in Perl.

Comment: Removed the bug you've added in an edit.

Comment: @AlanHaggaiAlavi even after that is fixed, the code after it gets executed in both parent and child because the `if` branch contains no `exit`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many problems with your script. Always:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

`local`ising special variables is a good practice. Only a variable containing the special value `undef` returns false for `defined`. So, every other value (even a `0`; which is the case here) returns true for `defined`. In the other script, the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) is wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $| = 1;

print "Before the child process\n";

unless (fork) {
    system("perl testing.pl");
    exit;
}

print "Before wait command\n";
wait;
print "After 20 secs of waiting\n";
```

Answer (score 7):

The [“Background Processes” section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Background-Processes) of the [perlipc documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) reads

> You can run a command in the background with:
>
> ```
> system("cmd &");
> ```
>
> The command’s `STDOUT` and `STDERR` (and possibly `STDIN`, depending on your shell) will be the same as the parent’s. You won't need to catch `SIGCHLD` because of the double-`fork` taking place; see below for details.

Adding an ampersand to the argument to `system` in your program can vastly simplify your main program.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

print "before the child process\n";

system("perl testing.pl &") == 0
  or die "$0: perl exited " . ($? >> 8);

print "before wait command\n";

wait;
die "$0: wait: $!" if $? == -1;

print "after 20 secs of waiting\n";
```

Comment: i missed that part by mistake, i have included that in the code

Comment: @dreamer, Greg Bacon was suggesting that as an alternative to using `fork`.

Answer (score 1):

`fork` return value handling is a bit tricky, indeed.
[Recent article by Aristotle](http://blogs.perl.org/users/aristotle/2012/10/concise-fork-idiom.html) features a nice and concise forking idiom, which, in your case, looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.010000;
use strict;
use warnings qw(all);

say 'before the child process';
given (fork) {
    when (undef) { die "couldn't fork: $!" }
    when (0) {
        exec $^X => 'testing.pl';
    } default {
        my $pid = $_;
        say 'before wait command';
        waitpid $pid, 0;
        say 'after 20 secs of waiting';
    }
}
```

Pay attention to `exec $^X => '...'` line: the **$^X** variable holds the full path to the current Perl executable, so the "right Perl version" will be guaranteed. Also, `system` call is pointless when you're pre-forking.