# Running RabbitMQ in background

Tags: perl, rabbitmq

I am using `RabbitMQ Messaging` service to run some background services. The problem I am facing is that I have keep open my command line which runs a script continuously:

```
perl receive_messages.pl
```

Is it possible that these scripts run in background as soon as I start my RabbitMQ server or not?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is “how to execute receive_messages.pl in background”.
And for example you can read this post:
[perl background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530345/perl-background-process)

Once created your background script, you can execute it after RabbitMQ in started, for example modifying directly the RabbitMQ start bash.

Anyway if you want `“embedded”` your script  you could write your own RabbitMQ Plug-in (https://www.rabbitmq.com/plugin-development.html) and execute the script in the plug-in.

Usually write a plug-in is not a good practice, because RabbitMQ crashes  if the plug-in crashes.